# I want the output to be printed after i finished entering the entire input, not showing the output for every line i inputted

Tags: c, codeblocks

so im new to CodeBlocks. I wonder if i could make the CodeBlocks to output my code after i put the entire input? Because my CodeBlocks always show the output for every line i inputted, it's kinda annoying. Sorry for my bad english. If u are confused, pls check the image i've provided, thank you.

[The number is my input, but CodeBlocks always show the 'YES' or 'NO'after i input a number of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93d8z.png)
[I want the output to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrITP.png).

Anyway, this is the code i'm using to make that output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int t, a, b, c;
scanf("%d", &t);
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a + b == c || b + c == a || a + c == b) {
        printf("YES\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("NO\n");
    }
}
    return 0;

}
```

I tried searching on YouTube and google any possible websites but still don't find any solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeblocks for competitive programming I suggest using vs code with cph judge extension where you don't have to write input every time it also helps to run all the test cases in one click.

In your case, I think you should try to print output in one file which I don't think you need so I suggest creating an array of output and printing at the last of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int t, a, b, c;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    char output[t][4];  //New string array which stores each output
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
        if (a + b == c || b + c == a || a + c == b) {
            strcpy(out[i],"YES");
        }
        else {
            strcpy(out[i],"NO");
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++) printf("%s\n",out[i]); //Print at last so you get output in the last
    return 0;
}
```

Now your output will be printed last in every compiler. Hope it helps.